# WPF Flicker issue when multiple controls refresh

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have simple WPF application. I have 5-6 DataGrid which refresh/reload intervals of seconds or minutes. all works fine. I also implemented a Marque/News ticker. Which scrolls smoothly. Problem is when news ticker is flickering when DataGrid update or refresh intervals. When I comment the grid refresh code the news ticker scrolls very smoothly. Where is the problem?

Comment: show the code snippet you are using

Comment: Problem is when news ticker is flickering when DataGrid update or refresh intervals ? what is double "when"  ?

Comment: I reload the grid on every second or minute. The news ticker may flicker at this moment, If i stop update grid every minute or second news ticker scroll very smoothly without flickering

Comment: I have solved this issue my own. I changes the whole application architecture and MVVM also.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a wild stab in the dark without being able to see your code I'd say that you're updating both your DataGrids and your ticker on the GUI thread, and that the data you're trying to present takes some time to retrieve (or there's a lot of it).

The solution to that problem (and it's a good idea anyway even if it's not the source of your problem) is to use a background thread to retrieve the data and store it locally (e.g. in a collection, or a DataTable) and have the GUI refresh itself periodically from the local data source rather than the remote one.